# Is the review counter a little buggy?

Tags: support, review

I currently have a little number `5` at the top of my screen (just to
the left of *“review”*). The tooltip says *“5 Total posts awaiting
review.”*, but when I click on it I get taken to an empty review page
(0 items on each category).

This has been on for a few days. The number varies, but it’s always wrong.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I don't think this is a question about the Emacs site.  It is a question about the Stack Exchange UI. But apparently the criterion for closing says that a question is OT if it is *neither* about the Emacs site *nor* about the S.E. software (!).  FWIW, that second criterion doesn't seem right to me. What's the point of having an Emacs *site-specific meta* if anything about S.E. is on topic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[It's not working! Should I blame caching?](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/)

But actually, it's more than caching. The number at the top of the screen is the total number of pending items in the queues that you can act on. This includes items that are still pending, but that you cannot act on: mainly items that you have already reviews, but also your own suggested edits, questions in the close queue that you've already voted to close, etc.

This has been reported [many](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233535/review-counts-in-top-bar-and-review-dont-match) [times](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236412/review-items-counter-is-stuck) [on](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238472/review-count-fix-it-or-lose-it) the [Main Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/). Making the number accurate for you has been declined because it would be too expensive to implement. I proposed an [approximation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237108/can-should-the-review-count-indicator-be-changed-to-be-colour-coded-status-ins/237140#237140) which [is under consideration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238472/review-count-fix-it-or-lose-it/238515#238515) but nothing has changed so far.